# Whether to return Nothing or just don't return anything at all

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Should a function that originally doesn't return a value return `Nothing` anyway (as Visual Studio puts a green squiggle in the `End Function` statement asking if you'd forget to return a value), or I can ignore VS' tip? What is the impact in returning `Nothing`, or anything at all?

tl;dr: Should this example code return `Nothing` or it is not needed? Elucidations are really welcome!

```
    Public Shared sCaminhoGravacaoXML As String = "C:\XMLData\"

    Public Shared Function VerificaPastasXML()

        If Not IsNothing(sCaminhoGravacaoXML) And sCaminhoGravacaoXML <> "" Then

            Dim sRaiz As String = sCaminhoGravacaoXML

            If Not FileIO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(sRaiz) Then
                FileIO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(sRaiz)
            End If

            If Not Directory.Exists(sRaiz & "tempXML") Then
                Dim diInfo As DirectoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(sRaiz & "tempXML")
                diInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory Or FileAttributes.Hidden
            End If

        Else
            sErroBaixaXML = "Não foi possível montar a estrutura de pastas para os arquivos" & vbCrLf & "XML de NFe, favor consultar os parâmetros da filial!"
        End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should this example code return Nothing or it is not needed?

Since it never returns a value, it should be a `Sub`. `Function` implies to the reader that a value is returned, so your function looks buggy as it is now, confusing everyone who has to maintain it.

Technically, a `Function` automatically returns the *default value* of the return data type if there is no explicit `return` statement. Thus, your function (which is implicitly declared with a return type of `Object`)¹ would return `Nothing`; a function with a return type of `Integer` would return `0`, etc.

Since *forgetting* to return a value is a common cause of errors, the warning is here to help you. If you *want* to return the default value, it is good practice to use an explicit `return` statement to make that clear.

---

¹ Please consider activating [`Option Strict`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454552/87698) to avoid such implicit declarations.

Comment: And this is why a hate vb :-(

Answer (score 0):

A function in vb.net must return something, compared with subs, that doesn't have a return value. If you don't want to return a value, just change it from Function to Sub.

Comment: Actually that would be my next question, If I should simply make it a `Sub` instead of a `Function`, thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not returning a value, and this is in fact VB.NET - consider using Sub instead of Function, which implies you are not returning a value.

However, in most other languages, it's ok to not return anything as the function will return null / Nothing on it's own.

Further, some code analysis tools will as you to always have a return statement one way or the other, though, so some developers will prefer you to explicitly state that for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function VerificaPastasXML() As Boolean
```

and

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sCaminhoGravacaoXML) Then Return False
    Try
        ' ... doSomething (technically you should handle exceptions separately, or check for return values instead.
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        sErroBaixaXML = "Não foi possível montar a estrutura de pastas para os arquivos" & vbCrLf & "XML de NFe, favor consultar os parâmetros da filial!"
        Return False
    End Try
```

you should return something to notify the calling procedure if the operation succeeded or failed.

tbh though, the logic to create the folder/file needs some work.

ie: `If Not VerificaPastasXML() Then : MsgBox("the operation failed") : Else : doSomething() : End If`.